# Set form value from url parameter

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I am using Typo3 10LTS and I would like to set the value of a form field with a parameter value from the URL.

E.g. the value "123" should be entered into the form field "field-1" via the URL [www.test-xyz.de/sidename?field-1=123](http://www.test-xyz.de/sidename?field-1=123).

Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: It might help to specify where that form is coming from. Is it in a template of your own extension, or e.g. in the forms-extension? If you have a controller to handle your form you can just get the params there, assign them to your template and use them as default value there.

Comment: I use the standard form extension of typo3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fluid**

Let's say we have a fluid link, with parameter `"123"`

```
<f:link.page pageUid="999" additionalParams="{param: '123'}" noCacheHash="true">Link to Form</f:link.page>
```

This sends the parameter to the page with the form, containing the value in the URL:

```
www.test-xyz.de/sitename?param=123
```

See: [link.page Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Page.html)

**jQuery**

We can now use a few lines of jQuery to populate a field with the value from the URL:

```
$(".myForm").each(function() {

    // Function to sanitize output
    
    function getURLParameter(name) {
      return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
    };
    
    // Populate the input field '.field1' with the parameter in the URL

    if (getURLParameter('param') !== null) {
        var value = getURLParameter('param');
        $('.field1').each(function(){ 
            $(this).val(value); 
        }); 
    };

});
```